# Space keypress on an HTML Label interpreted as checkbox click

Tags: html, dom-events

When I add `'click'` event handler on an HTML checkbox with a label, then space keypress on the label causes the checkbox's click event handler to be executed. I would like to prevent that. (The checkbox itself is hidden / not visible - this is done in some version of Bootstrap framework used in my code).

HTML:

```html
<body>
  <label for="checkbox" id="label">Click on me, I am Label for <strong>hidden</strong> Checkbox</label>

  <!-- checkbox is not visible -->
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" style="opacity: 0" />

  <!-- to be filled by JavaScript code -->
  <div id="checkboxValue"></div>
</body>
```

JavaScript code:

```js
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

const checkbox: HTMLInputElement = document.querySelector('#checkbox');
const checkboxValue: HTMLDivElement = document.querySelector('#checkboxValue');

function updateCheckbox() {
  checkboxValue.innerHTML = `Checkbox ${
    checkbox.checked ? '✔️ (checked)' : '❌ (unchecked)'
  }`;
}

// event handler for the checkbox being executed also for Space keypress:
fromEvent(checkbox, 'click').subscribe((event) => {
  console.log('checkbox CLICK -------')
  updateCheckbox();
});

updateCheckbox();
```

Open the Stackblitz console, click the `Click on me, I am Label for hidden Checkbox`.
Then press the space key and see the click handler being executed.

Demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-4zryhd?file=index.ts).

Comment: this is because you use the for attribute in the label. Click (with mouse or keyboard) on the label with trigger the click on the input. This works with any form element

Answer (score 0):

If a label has keyboard focus, pressing the <kbd>Space</kbd> key also raises the Click event.

If you want to remove focus, you can add a blur event (on the label) to remove focus so spacebar won't function to click the button :

```
e.target.blur();
```

Comment: I would like to keep focus and disable space keypress to emit as click event on checkbox.

Comment: I want the opposite: I want spacebar to toggle any _focused_ checkbox, infinitely. Right now, spacebar toggle's a checkbox once, then focus is lost. Hitting spacebar again scrolls the page downward (because nothing is focused).